# Standardization of Data

Tags: descriptive-statistics, normalization, standardization

I have a dataset which consists of `Sales` for `Product1` and `Product2`. 
It also tells if the `Product1` and `Product2` were on promotion or not: it has amount spent on promotions for their promotion if they were on promotion.

Lastly it has number of stores in which the product was on sale.

The data is as follows

```
+--------------+----------+------------------+----------+-------------+----------+
| Dollar Sales            | Promotion Dollar            | Stores Sold            |
+--------------+----------+------------------+----------+-------------+----------+
| Product1     | Product2 | Product1         | Product2 | Product1    | Product2 |
| 20           | 18       | 20               | 0        | 221         | 101      |
| 14           | 11       | 17               | 0        | 244         | 253      |
| 13           | 13       | 20               | 10       | 243         | 286      |
| 14           | 0        | 0                | 16       | 108         | 278      |
| 13           | 0        | 0                | 18       | 209         | 256      |
| 18           | 12       | 0                | 0        | 100         | 172      |
+--------------+----------+------------------+----------+-------------+----------+
```

My main concern is how do I normalize/standardize the data so that I can compare different columns.

I want to see the lift in sales due to promotion for which I want to calculate baseline sales.

But the sales is also a function of the number of stores where the product is sold apart from just promotion.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't see this as a problem for standardization or normalization at all.

**Watch out: standardization and normalization have a range of meanings across statistics and machine learning.** You should not assume that readers know 
what you mean. But I can't see that anything I have seen under either name would help here, yet there is still a need to be precise. Either term often means some kind of scaling, say (value $-$ mean) /SD  to  ensure mean 0 and SD 1 or (value $-$ min) / (max $-$ min) to ensure all values lie between 0 and 1.

You have a problem in predicting sales from promotion and number of stores sold.

Whether you predict the products separately or together is a delicate question depending closely on the products: are they competing or are they quite different? I have heard folklore that big stores put beer and baby stuff side by side, so that fathers buying baby stuff make it clear that they are macho enough by buying beer too. If it's two brands of toothpaste or kinds of ballpoint pen, the story is quite different. Most purchases are going to be one or the other not both.

Either way, the problem to me shouts regression. As some stores might sell nothing in a period, and some stores might sell much more, it's not obvious that plain or vanilla regression is quite enough. I would lean towards generalised linear models with logarithmic link.

If you can get a predictive relationship, then you can estimate sales with no promotion for some given number of stores.

Standardization would just throw away information you really need for a good prediction.

Comment: But as the number of stores varies, the sales will also vary. That's the reason I thought there is a need for normalization.

Comment: Brand 1 and Brand 2 is not sold in same number of stores so I fee directl comparison of there sales wont be correct

Comment: The number of stores varying is precisely why it could be a useful predictor. Again, you don't really explain why you thought standardization would help. Otherwise if products should be considered separately, fine by me; it's not clear why your question mentions two products then.

Comment: May be then my understanding about standardization is wrong. If the above is my data, how do I approach about estimating the effect of promotion on `brand1` on the sales of `brand1` and similarly on the sales of `brand2`

Comment: I believe I've already answered that. If regression is new to you, you need a good text  on it or careful study of the documentation of whatever statistical software you're using. From your posts on SO in particular I guess that you're mostly using SQL and also Excel. I am afraid that Excel is very limited in statistical modelling. I won't get into what else you might use; in practice much depends on what is accessible to you and many other details that are personal to you.

Comment: You've already asked questions here about regression, so it's not completely new to you.

Comment: Yes, I do know regression. I was just wondering that keeping my dependent variable as `Product1 Sales` and rest all of them as independent variable,  will the coefficients help me to answer questions like 1. When I promote brand1 is there any effect on sales of brand2 ?

Comment: Now you're asking a different question. Fair enough, but make it a different thread. Whether products and brands are the same or different and what the data are would need to be totally clear.